# Setting up route-guard in Vue.js/Firebase login authentication interface

Tags: javascript, firebase, vue.js, vue-router

I am building a basic Vue.js/Firebase authentication interface based on the following tutorial: (part 1 - https://medium.com/@oleg.agapov/basic-single-page-application-using-vue-js-and-firebase-part-1-9e4c0c11a228), (part 2 - https://medium.com/@oleg.agapov/basic-single-page-application-using-vue-js-and-firebase-part-2-143a3084266f). I have built the app in its entirety and it mostly works except for some aspects of the route-guard. After creating an account I am able to successfully log in and store the account info in the firestore database. The problem is that after signing in, the manual redirecting of "http://localhost:8080/home" to "http://localhost:8080/" causes the home page to transition back to a landing page that prompts the user to either sign up or sign in...while the user is still signed in. "http://localhost:8080/" is the route for the landing page, but inputting "http://localhost:8080/" while the user is logged in to the home page should logically just redirect to the home page. How can I set this up so that inputting "http://localhost:8080/" while logged returns me to the home page, instead of the landing page? Here is what I have for my routing, based on the tutorial:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import Router from 'vue-router'
import firebase from 'firebase'

const routerOptions = [
  { path: '/', component: 'Landing' },
  { path: '/signin', component: 'Signin' },
  { path: '/signup', component: 'Signup' },
  { path: '/home', component: 'Home', meta: { requiresAuth: true } },
  { path: '*', component: 'NotFound' }
]

const routes = routerOptions.map(route => {
  return {
    ...route,
    component: () => import(`@/components/${route.component}.vue`)
  }
})

Vue.use(Router)

const router = new Router({
  mode: 'history',
  routes
})

router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  const requiresAuth = to.matched.some(record => record.meta.requiresAuth)
  const isAuthenticated = firebase.auth().currentUser
  if (requiresAuth && !isAuthenticated) {
    next('/signin')
  } else {
    next()
  }
})

export default router
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is even more easy way. Just rewrite your code like this:

```
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  const requiresAuth = to.matched.some(record => record.meta.requiresAuth)
  const isAuthenticated = firebase.auth().currentUser
  if(isAuthenticated && to.path === '/') {
    next('/home')
  }
  if (requiresAuth && !isAuthenticated) {
    next('/signin')
  } else {
    next()
  }
})
```

Choose the way you like. Both should work

Answer (score 0):

Try this. Change your router file. `store` is file with your vuex:

```
import store from './store'
const routerOptions = [
    { path: '/', component: 'Landing',
        beforeEnter(to, from, next) {
            if(store.getters.isAuthenticated) {
                next('/home')
            } else {
               next()
            }
        }
    },
    { path: '/signin', component: 'Signin' },
    { path: '/signup', component: 'Signup' },
    { path: '/home', component: 'Home', meta: { requiresAuth: true } },
    { path: '*', component: 'NotFound' }
]
```

Comment: thank you for the feedback. I am still not fully sure how to implement what you described. How can I integrate this with the existing router file? Won't I still need to import Firebase somehow? Could you expand on this?

Comment: No, you don't need to touch Firebase settings anymore. They're already fine. Look at your project structure. I think its ./src/store/index.js - your vuex stuff, and ./src/router/index.js - your router stuff. You need from router file get your store (vuex) data. If I'm right about your project structure then change first string to `import store from '../store'`

Comment: I mean this code from the second part of that tutorial: `getters: {
  isAuthenticated (state) {
    return state.user !== null && state.user !== undefined
  }
}`